# Count Total by Date

Tags: sum, sas, proc

I have the following Dataset:

```
Date          Occupation      Employment
01/01/2005        1             Management
01/01/2005        1             Management
01/01/2005        1             Science
01/01/2006        1             Science
05/01/2006        1             Operational
01/01/2006        1             Science
for each month and year from January 2005 until December 2015.
```

What I want is Total for each category of the variable Employment for each month and year.

So for the example above it would be something like the following:

```
Date            Occupation_Total       Employment
01/01/2005           2                 Management 
01/01/2005           1                 Science
01/01/2006           2                 Science
01/01/2006           1                 Operational
```

What is the best way to go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Please post what you've tried. Hint: proc freq + yearmon7. Format for the date variable.

Answer (score 2):

In a data step, extract the month and year using the month and year functions. 
Create a key by concatenating the extracted months and years. Then you can use proc sql to summarize, try the following:

```
data ds;
set ds;
month=month(date);
year=year(date);
key=catx("_",month,year);
run;

Proc sql;
create table summary as
select employment,key,sum(occupation) as occupation_total
from ds
group by employment,key;
quit;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is generating summary statistics by a group. Proc Means or Proc Freq are appropriate. I'll demo proc means in case not all Occupation have a value of 1.

```
proc means data=have nway;
class date employment;
format date yymon7.;
var occupation;
output out=want sum(occupation)=total_occupation p25(occupation)=occupation_p25;
run;

proc print;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks. This and other codes worked perfectly, although I think the date format you meant is yymon7. 
Does the output out also calculate the percentile too? Like the percentile of occupation for each month/year by employment?

Comment: Yes you can use proc means to calculate percentiles. I'm not sure that's at the correct level that you're looking for but hope it gives you an idea of the code. Proc means has a few specific percentiles, but proc univariate can calculate any percentile.

Answer (score 0):

You have to group data by using operator

If first.Employment ....  If last.Employment....

Here is the explanation for this operators, it helps to group data then use sum

http://www.pauldickman.com/teaching/sas/set_by.php